# How to remove semicolon from a column and replace it with a line feed in Access with SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

I want to remove semicolons and create new columns to separate the years with different columns in this table:

[image: My table]

I tried to replace it with the following code but I had this result:

[image: My result]

This result only deletes what comes after the first semicolon and does not replace subsequent semicolons with new columns with the years, thanks for the answers:

```
SELECT Province, REPLACE( Annee_Guerre, ';' , CHR(13) + CHR(10))
FROM Feuil1;
```

Comment: Are you sure? Put something else in the REPLACE besides CHR(13) + CHR(10) and see what you get. SELECT Province, REPLACE( Annee_Guerre, ';' , 'foo')
FROM Feuil1;

Comment: It works fine. The problem is you don't see new lines if you don't expand the row size

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider replacing the ";" with vbCrLf in the VBA code using a recordset and a loop. Queries usually do not respond well to Cr and Lf in the strings.